# insert JList into GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, jlist

I have a problem related to `JList`. I'm getting the following layout.

```
JTextField | Button 1 | Button 2
Button 3   | Button 4 | Button 5
```

This is the layout I'm getting:

```
JTextField | Button 1 | Button 2
Button 3   | Button 4 | Button 5
```

As you can see, I do not have `JList` in between. I did try inserting a list component there but when I did it, the `GridLayout` would push the list beside button 2. I only want the list to be my itself in between those.

```
package ManyThings;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
javax.swing.JTextField;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
JTextField t1;
t1=new JTextField();
p1.add(new JTextField());             
p1.add(new JButton("Search"));
p1.add(new JButton("Clear"));
frame.add(p1);

JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
p2.add(new JButton("Add"));
p2.add(new JButton("Detail"));
p2.add(new JButton("Remove"));
frame.add(p2);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Expecting the following layout.

```
JTextField | Button 1 | Button 2
JList
Button 3   | Button 4 | Button 5
```

Comment: Either use multiple containers (one for each row) and make use of multiple `GridLayout`s or use a different layout manager

Comment: You'll need to use GridBagLayout or compose multiple layouts together.

Comment: Hey please check the updated code. I did use 2 gridLayout. but it would always add the 2nd panel and not the 1st, meaning, it only adds the bottom buttons.

Comment: @SeanD But, when did you add the `JList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Compound layouts

Make use of multiple containers, using different layout managers (as required)

[image: Compound layouts]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

            JPanel topRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            topRow.add(new JTextField(10));
            topRow.add(new JButton("Search"));
            topRow.add(new JButton("Clear"));

            add(topRow);
            add(new JScrollPane(new JList()));

            JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Add"));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Detail"));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Remove"));

            add(bottomRow);
        }

    }
}
```

## Different layout managers

Use different layout managers to better meet the requirements of the individual components

[image: Different layouts]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel topRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            topRow.add(new JTextField(10));
            topRow.add(new JButton("Search"));
            topRow.add(new JButton("Clear"));

            JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Add"));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Detail"));
            bottomRow.add(new JButton("Remove"));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            add(topRow, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(bottomRow, gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JScrollPane(new JList()), gbc);

        }

    }
}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details